# Vue js error push with method sendMessage

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have method:

```
 props: ['convId'],
  data() {
        return {
            messages: [],
            newMessage: ''
        };
 },

 methods: {
        sendMessage() {
            axios.post('/sendMessage/' + this.convId, { message: this.newMessage })
                    .then(response =>  this.messages.push(response.data.data));

            this.messages.push(newMessage);

            this.newMessage = '';

            console.log(this.messages.id); //TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
        }
  },
```

When I try get updated this.messages. I get undifined properties of this object. Why?

In request I return object:

```
{"body":"test","user_id":1,"type":"text","conversation_id":1,"updated_at":"2018-06-04 13:15:27","created_at":"2018-06-04 13:15:27","id":16,"conversation":{"id":1,"private":1,"data":null,"created_at":"2018-06-01 12:54:33","updated_at":"2018-06-04 13:15:27","users":[{"id":1,"name":"Axer","email":"test@gmail.com","created_at":"2018-06-01 12:35:37","updated_at":"2018-06-01 12:35:37","pivot":{"conversation_id":1,"user_id":1,"created_at":"2018-06-01 12:54:33","updated_at":"2018-06-01 12:54:33"}},{"id":2,"name":"Testumus","email":"teadasdasd@gmail.com","created_at":"2018-06-01 12:46:30","updated_at":"2018-06-01 12:46:30","pivot":{"conversation_id":1,"user_id":2,"created_at":"2018-06-01 12:54:33","updated_at":"2018-06-01 12:54:33"}}]}}
```

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified `newMessage` variable. Maybe you wanted to insert `this.newMessage`.

If you are trying to get the result thats been insert maybe you can return the database data into the response and then push in message , that way you'll be able to get `id` and other column which you are using to log it out on console.

```
 axios.post('/sendMessage/' + this.convId, { message: this.newMessage })
       .then((response) {  
             this.messages.push(response.data.data) // Fetched message from server
             this.newMessage = '';
             console.log(this.messages.id); 
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

```
         props: ['convId'],
          data() {
                return {
                    messages: [],
                    newMessage: ''
                };
         },

         methods: {
                sendMessage() {
                    axios.post('/sendMessage/' + this.convId, { message: this.newMessage })
                            .then((response) {  
                                  this.messages.push(response.data.data);
                                  this.messages.push(newMessage);
                                  this.newMessage = '';
                                  console.log(this.messages.id); 
                             });
                }
          },
```

Try this.